# ImageView onTouchListener with Gallery

Tags: android

I want to add to the `ImageView` the pinch feature. So I extended the `ImageView` and I implemented the `OnTouchListener` interface. The `ImageView` is clickable. The feature itsel works, but when I use the custom `ImageView` with the `Gallery` widget, the gallery does not swipe. If I set `focusable` and `clickable` to false, gallery swipe. How can I let they work together?

Code for the custom ImageView

```
    public class Custom6 extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {


        public Custom6(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setClickable(true);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public Custom6(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setClickable(true);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public Custom6(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setClickable(true);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           return true;
       }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if you are using listview or not...

Comment: nope I am using the Gallery widget

Comment: Actually in listview i have face similar problem... because when we set any child as clickable then their parent not able to get that event as child are tightly binded with their parents so only one can have same event i have used a dummy child view in that case and use broadcast receiver to work on events.

Comment: On more thing i want to know is why you have set it as clickable because if you will not set anything in your xml then also you will recieve event... in on click listner and on touch listner

Answer (score -1):

Return false in ontouch lister and then try i hope it will work...

Comment: have you tried same code without using setClickable(true); I think it will recieve on touch event in that case also...